# Typescript: Misunderstanding about duck typing

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm studying Typescript reading Handbooks & Docs. And i'm just curious about how Typescript Duck Typing Works.

For example, this code provides Type error (using Typescript official Playground)

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

const p: Point = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
}

function printPoint(p: Point) {
    console.log(p.x + p.y);
}

printPoint(p);
```

but this code does not provides Type error

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

const p = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
}

function printPoint(p: Point) {
    console.log(p.x + p.y);
}

printPoint(p);
```

i thinks the problem is related to Typescript's Duck Typing,
but i could not understand why argument's type system & constant's type system works in different way.

did i misunderstand about the Duck Typing?
const p contains x, y, so i think const p: Point should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript enforces different levels of strictness depending on what you're doing. When you create a variable with an explicit type, typescript is very strict about what must be there, not allowing any extra properties. An extra property is probably a bug in your code, since your creating a value but then immediately assigning a type which makes that value inaccessible. So the extra strictness helps you catch such bugs.

When you try to assign one variable to another, including passing a variable into a function, typescript does a looser check. The two variables just need to be **compatible** with each other, which roughly means they need to have at least the listed properties with the right types, but it's ok if it also has extra properties. This looser level of checking is part of the way typescript supports subtypes and subclasses. You should be able to pass a subclass in where a base class is called for (the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), but the subclass will often have extra properties.

See this link for more information on type compatibility: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: That is the answer what i'm looking for :) Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The first code showed TypeError because the `Point` interface does not have a member `z`. The second did not have type error, because in the function, all the properties referenced(`x` and `y`) exist in type `Point`. This is due to Duck Typing and it being accepted as a `Point` or not because `z` member is not referenced. Inside the function, if you try to use `p.z`, you will get type error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. you mean constatns declaration with interface does not use Duck Typing? while function arguments uses Duck Typing

Comment: Almost. You did not declare a type for the variable `p` in the second code. This allows it to be accepted and use Duck Typing. In TypeScript, if two objects have the same properties their types are the same and they can be converted.

Comment: I finally got the point when I tested with few more codes.
`printPoint({x: 1, y:2, z:3})` container error because `{x:1, y:2, z:3}`is not a Point type
but when i type like this
`const a = {x:1, y:2, z:3}`
`printPoint(a)`
it uses duck typing. 
thank you for Ur insight!

Answer (score 0):

A functions arguments and return type values in TS are checked to ensure they are subtype compatible as long as `strictFunctionTypes` is enabled in the tsconfig. This is why you're seeing the behaviour in your second example as `typeof p` is as a subtype of `Point`.

When you type a variable or constant it is strictly typed, subtypes or extended types would only be allowed if you explicitly allow them.

```
interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

// There are many ways to do this but you could for example allow
// an extended type to have a subtype of Point and any number 
// of string properties that have number values.
type ExtendedPoint = Point & Record<string, number>;

// Allow subtypes of Point
type UnrestrictedPoint = Partial<Point>;
```

[TS Playground: Your original example but allowing subtypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRmQbwFDKHIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANwFECe5VdjeAvnnmCwAOKAKLFIIACYRJGLMgC8aTOGQAyZACUICdFEkAeAM5gooAOYAaCjXpQAfEzy6QJ5IPJiJ02SuxL8IhJyAEZLZkI2ZAAmcKCAL3IAZh4%20GEoQBDBgdBB3M3A5cAAKD2UsAEpcCOQXI3QAGwgAOgb0c1Lm4mQAandmlgqmXjxBArAisFKhoA)